# UNION two tables SQL / Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to **union two tables**. **One** has almost **400 columns** and milions of rows. The **second** **20 columns** and about 500 000 rows. 
I am wondering what is the best approach to union both tables - the union is difficult to implement as I have only 20 matching columns and for the other ones I am getting error due to incorrect datatypes.
**Now** I am using **full outer join** and then **COALESCE** to retrieve the data in the final output, but due the slow performance the query cannot be used.

Do you have any suggestion how to achieve union of two tables, but not using **union** or **full outer join**?

Or any tips how to avoid datatype mismatch during union?

The example what I am doing now:

```
SELECT 
 t1.A
,t1.B
,t1.C
,t1.D
,COALESCE(t1.E,t2.E) as E
,COALESCE(t1.F,t2.F) as F
,COALESCE(t1.G,t2.G) as G
FROM  
t1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
 t2
ON 1=2
```

For t1 I have 400 columns, for t2 20 columns (these 20 is used in the coalesce function) to have them in the output

Data are from diffrent systems, only 20 columns are pretty similar so there is requirements to have all data in one table (actually in the view)

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to UNION such different tables? Show us a minimized example of what you want. [mcve]

Comment: I edited my first post, hope this helps

Comment: jarlh is asking this, because it seems a strange task to union two such different and big tables. We wonder what it is actually you want to achieve? Get all those millions  of rows in one data set and then? Why do you think you need this gigantic agglutinate data set?

Comment: There is requirement to have this data in one table due to later reporting (visualization etc.). So as some columns are similar (like amount or date) it would be helpfull to have this in one data set

Comment: I'm not convinced. I wouldn't union employee and company table for instance only because both have a name and an address; they are two different things. Anyway, I cannot help. Teradata behaves strange concerning nulls it seems, so you must cast them all to the data types you need.

Comment: I think maybe you are mis-using the word *union*.  Union means to basically combine two tables vertically (if you have 10 rows in each, you end up with 20 rows in your result).  In your code, you are attempting to *join* them, but you are not giving any valid join criteria.

Comment: If you join them (not unionize as you refer to it) on the columns that are also primary indexes (aka cluster indexes), you shouldn't have trouble getting a report out of large datasets, esp. if you use aggregations everywhere, which is what TD is best for. If you know the join condition please add it, and we can try to advise on possibly rebuilding the DDL.